# How can I add certain commands to .bash_history permanently?

Tags: bash, history

I use bash and I sometimes have to type some very long commands for certain tasks. These long commands are not regularly used and generally gets overwritten in .bash_history file by the time I use them again. How can I add certain commands to .bash_history permanently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the usual way to do that would be to store your long commands as either aliases or bash functions. A nice way to organise them would the to put them all in a file (say `$HOME/.custom_funcs`) then source it from `.bashrc`.

If you *really really* want to be able to load commands into your bash history, you can use the `-r` option of the `history` command.

From the [man page](http://ss64.com/bash/history.html):

```
-r    Read the current history file and append its contents to the history list.
```

Just store all your entries in a file, and whenever you need your custom history loaded simply run `history -r <your_file>`.

Here's a demo:

```
[me@home]$ history | tail  # see current history
 1006  history | tail
 1007  rm x
 1008  vi .custom_history
 1009  ls
 1010  history | tail
 1011  cd /var/log
 1012  tail -f messages
 1013  cd
 1014  ls -al
 1015  history | tail  # see current history

[me@home]$ cat $HOME/.custom_history  # content of custom history file
echo "hello world"
ls -al /home/stack/overflow
(cd /var/log/messages; wc -l *; cd -)

[me@home]$ history -r $HOME/.custom_history   # load custom history

[me@home]$ history | tail  # see updated history
 1012  tail -f messages
 1013  cd
 1014  ls -al
 1015  history | tail  # see current history
 1016  cat .custom_history
 1017  history -r $HOME/.custom_history
 1018  echo "hello world"
 1019  ls -al /home/stack/overflow
 1020  (cd /var/log/messages; wc -l *; cd -)
 1021  history | tail  # see updated history
```

Note how entries `1018-1020` weren't actually run but instead were loaded from the file.

At this point you can access them as you would normally using the `history` or `!` commands, or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> shortcuts and the likes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

I vaguely remember reading somewhere adding certain character (& or something else) before a command can make bash to remember the command forever. I am looking for that answer. If I don't get that answer then I will use the approach you gave.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a functionality, so I'd be interested to know if your do find something like that :) If you can't find such a feature, you can still get close to that behaviour by creating a function that appends commands to the custom history file. Good luck.

Comment: Great answer. The only thing I'd add is, "... aliases, bash functions, *or scripts*.".

Comment: Many thanks Dan. I did consider including *"... calls to bash script for more involved operations"* but decided to leave it out since we're specifically looking at alternatives to bash history entries. Commands that make useful history entries are *usually* the more straight-forward ones, so making a separate bash script for each one might be an overkill. There are of course exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I will go with the approach you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

How about just extending the size of your bash history file with the shell variable

**HISTFILESIZE**

Instead of the default 500 make it something like 2000

Answer (score 0):

The canonical answer is to create scripts containing these commands.

**Edit** Supposing you have the following history entries;

```
find /var/www -name '*.html' -exec fgrep '<title>' {} /dev/null \;
find ~/public_html -name '*.php' -exec fgrep include {} /dev/null \;
```

... you can try to isolate the parameters into a function something like this;

```
r () {
  find "$1" -name "*.$2" -exec fgrep "$3" {} /dev/null \;
}
```

... which you could use like this, to repeat the history entries from above:

```
r /var/www      html '<title>'
r ~/public_html php  include
```

Obviously, the step is then not very long to create a proper script with defaults, parameter validation, etc.  (Hint: you could usefully default to the current directory for the path, and no extension for the file name, and add options like `--path` and `--ext` to override the defaults when you want to; then there will be only one mandatory argument to the script.)

Typically, you would store the script in `$HOME/bin` and make sure this directory is added to your `PATH` from your `.profile` or similar.  For functions, these are usually defined in `.profile`, or a separate file which is `source`d from this file.

Having it in a central place also helps develop it further; for example, for precision and perhaps some minor added efficiency, you might want to add `-type f` to the `find`  command; now there is only one place to remember to edit, and you will have it fixed for good.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29) for your command.

> alias myalas='...a very long command here...'

Comment: Functions or scripts are preferred to aliases; aliases cannot handle positional parameters, for example.

Comment: Aliasing is not helpful in my case. I need to edit the command before executing it.

Comment: Then indeed you have to use a script that takes parameters.